# Why do some emojis only return the code? utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, mariadb, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm saving message post data in my database using the utf8mb4 charset.

This works for the vast majority of emojis, saving and rendering them correctly, but there are some that only return the code.

Like this one :

Which is the following : https://emojipedia.org/nauseated-face/

Is there anything I can do to make these missing ones work?

Server type: **MariaDB**

Server version: **10.0.32-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)**

Table Charset : **utf8mb4**

Column Collation: **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

DB connection is declaring correctly :

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4;db_collat=utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
               $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: I can see just fine in this post. I assume if you are just seeing the code for it, it is because your current font doesn't support that character.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody else reacted to this so I'm going to follow it up myself.

The issue wasn't actually anything to do with how it was being stored in the database.

It's browser based. It turns out that not all browsers can display all emoji's - I didn't know this!

For example, the emoji I mentioned above renders on Chrome and Safari, but not on Firefox.

I hope it saves somebody else the time I wasted trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Also looks fine for me in Firefox. What do you have your default fonts set to in Firefox settings? Are they the same default fonts as in Chrome and Safari? I use DejaVu fonts across all browsers and have no issues with your example ( https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/ )

Comment: I haven't set any fonts in any of my browsers. Didn't even know that was an option to be honest and certainly shouldn't expect your average web user to know about that either. Will look into this though thanks.